# How to prevent numbers in the input box and just display text?

Tags: javascript

I found a script that works but I have no idea how it is working.

The `split()` method this example uses is giving me painful headache. Does anyone have an idea of how that `split()` method is working in this example? Can we pass numbers as first argument to `split()` method? Is that a separator, if it is why is it not enclosed within quotes?

**Script**

```
function noNumbers(field) {
   for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      field.value = field.value.split(i).join("");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
   <form>
   Type some text (numbers not allowed):
    <input type="text" onkeyup="noNumbers(this);" />
   </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically `noNumbers` takes the string and splits it into an array at the given token in this case the number stored in `i`. Afterwards the array gets joined again by using empty strings between the parts.

Since you do this for all digits your result doesn't contain any numbers.

#### Example

```
"1213Test".split(0).join("")
  == ["1213Test"].join("")
  == "1213Test"

"1213Test".split(1).join("")
  == ["","2","3Test"].join("")
  == "23Test"

"23Test".split(2).join("")
  == ["","3Test"].join("")
  == "3Test"

"3Test".split(3).join("")
  == ["","Test"].join("")
  == "Test"
```

If you get confused because `i` is an integer: `split` takes strings as arguments, so `split(i)` is the same as `split(i.toString())`.

Comment: Thank u.well explained but at the end u said split() takes only string as an argument ,than if we pass nubers to it does the split method automatically converts it to string...

Comment: recently i tried placing only number as an splitter to split method with no quote but it worked.....I now is sure tht split method automatically converts the given argument to string....

Comment: @maizer4ever - javascript in most cases is very 'forgiving' in terms of type conversion. This itself, if not understood correctly, is one of the biggest pitfalls of most newbies. Javascript, in the default form, will attempt to convert certain types into the required type if it can, and throw an exception only when it can't or has been prohibited to perform a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The script in this case loops the decimal digits `0, 1, 2...9` and for every digit it makes a `split(digit).join()`. The split method returns an array of characters without the digits. Like:

```
"This 1s an example".split(1)
["This ", "s an example"]
```

And with `join("")` it just joins the array back to string:

```
["This ", "s an example"].join("")
"This s an example"
```

Comment: how can the split() method takes argument as an integer.I never heard tht..Even if it is a number ,it must be quoted.....

Comment: I think it makes a conversion for the integer. You could pass a regular expression fro the split method also. `"th1s is an example".split(/\d/)` makes the same thing. And might be more effective than to make the for loop every time.

Comment: recently i tried placing only number as an splitter to split method with no quote but it worked.....I now is sure tht split method automatically converts the given argument to string...